# where is the default initilizer in the code?

Tags: niftynet

I've tried find the default initilizer in the code but the framework is complicated, so I decided to directly ask here.  Where can I find the default initializer? Is there any configuarable parameter in the 'ini' file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the options are available in [`engine/application_factory`](https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/blob/v0.3.0/niftynet/engine/application_factory.py#L137), which imports classes from [`engine/application_initializer`](https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/blob/v0.3.0/niftynet/engine/application_initializer.py#L15).